# Calling the afterrender on each click on same element

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a dropdown menu that I want to call every time it is rendered. Right now it is called once, when I click on the dropdown menu. The subsequent times I click the dropdown menu, the afterrender doesn't seem to react anymore, untill I refresh the page. How can I make the `afterrender` react everytime I click the dropdown menu? Maybe it's a whole other property I should use for this?

```
                     afterrender: function(e) {
                        alert("Render");
                    }
```

As an example, say I do something like this:

```
                      var i = 0;
                      afterrender: function(e) {
                            alert(i++);                           
                      }
```

"i" will never get incremented, as the afterrender only works one time once the dropdown menu is clicked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `afterrender( this, eOpts )` Fires after the component rendering is
>   finished.
>
> The `afterrender` event is fired after this Component has been rendered,
>   been postprocessed by any afterRender method defined for the
>   Component.

This happens only once - after render.

What you need is this:

> `expand( field, eOpts )` Fires when the field's picker is expanded.

This event will fire as many times as you click/expand your `combobox`.